# @ionic/storage npm installation error while trying to install in ionic 4 project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic4, storage

when trying to install @ionic/storage, i am facing with the error
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...30fd3be6a8198deb74a",'

my cli version:  "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",

How to resolve this error .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link , hope it will help
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage

Advise : I prefer to user Locastorage(JS concept) over Ionic storage. Localstorage is bit more faster and easier to use than Ionic storage. Let me show some functions that I generally use for Storage. Make sure these codes are pasted inside a service so that you can access it from any component.

//Set Data

```
setLocalStorageItem(id: string, data: string) {
    localStorage.setItem(id, data);
  }
```

//Get Data

```
 getLocalStorageItem(data: string): string {
        return localStorage.getItem(data);
      }
```

//Remove data

```
 removeLocalStorageItem(data) {
    localStorage.removeItem(data);
  }
```